# Get WatchOS Digital Crown value

Tags: swift, watchkit

I've been doing some research about making Apple Watch apps, but I'm having some trouble getting the value of the Digital Crown. I looked at the WKCrownSequencer but not sure what to do with it. Could someone show me how I would go about getting a variable with values 1-10 that change when you turn the Digital Crown. Thanks!

Comment: In SwiftUI, this became much easier to do: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-read-the-digital-crown-on-watchos-using-digitalcrownrotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to conform your `InterfaceController` subclass to `WKCrownDelegate` and implement the `crownDidRotate` method.

If you want your value to be between 1 and 10, you just need to implement some simple logic for checking what would the value be when you added the `rotationalDelta` and if it would be out of the range 1-10, map value to either 1 or 10, depending on which direction the new value would exceed. I have assumed you want `value` to be `Int`, if not, just remove the conversion of `rotationalDelta` to `Int` and `value` will be `Double`.

Keep in mind, that a `rotationalDelta` of 1.0 represents a full rotation of the crown and `rotationalDelta` changes its sign based on the direction of the rotation.

```
class MyInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WKCrownDelegate {
    var value = 1
    @IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        crownSequencer.delegate = self
    }

    func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {
        let newValue = value + Int(rotationalDelta)
        if newValue < 1 {
            value = 1
        } else if newValue > 10 {
            value = 10
        } else {
            value = newValue
        }
        label.setText("Current value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! When implementing this would I need a new class because I tried to put WKInterfaceController and WKCrownDelegate into class Game scene, but it has issues with SKScene which is already in there.

Comment: Please include your class definition in the question so I can help, without context I cannot be sure what is the cause of this issue. But you definitely need to make that `InterfaceController` class conform to the `WKCrownDelegate` protocol that you want to control with the crown.

Comment: You should add crownSequencer.focus() to awake(withContext after setting delegate

Answer (score 1):

## After watchOS 3

After watchOS3 it's possible to take value of Digital Crown. Check [this documentation on Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer)

Basically you need to use [WKCrownDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate) in your View Controller. An example code will something like this:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    self.crownSequencer.delegate = self;
    [self.crownSequencer focus];
}

- (void)crownDidRotate:(WKCrownSequencer *)crownSequencer rotationalDelta:(double)rotationalDelta {
    self.totalDelta = self.totalDelta + rotationalDelta;
    [self updateLabel];
}

- (void)updateLabel {
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.totalDelta]];
}
```

### What is rotationalDelta

A value of 1.0 appears to indicate that the crown has completed a full rotation.

#### Warning

Please don't use this code directly, it's just an example. Check documentation from Apple's site first.